# Google Script - javascript function to send JSON POST request

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

For a spreadsheet Im building in google drive, I want to pull my balances off a trading website. I have a function which works with the JSON GET method, but now I need to find a function that works for JSON POST data. The function should use 3 parameters, so I can select those on the spreadsheet:

1. url.
2. key (API key)
3. sign (secret)

These are the headers to send with the function!

The site (poloniex.com/api) has the following requirements for a request:

```
All calls to the trading API are sent via HTTP POST to https://poloniex.com/tradingApi and must contain the following headers:

Key - Your API key.
Sign - The query's POST data signed by your key's "secret" according to the HMAC-SHA512 method.
Additionally, all queries must include a "nonce" POST parameter. The nonce parameter is an integer which must always be greater than the previous nonce used.
```

So, can anyone provide me with a working version of .gs or point me to a good source.
Also, I have no clue how to write the code for a nonce.

Comment: how it worked in the end?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29) describes the optional parameters you can use. Set the parameter `method` to "post" to send a POST request instead of a GET.

You can use [`Utilities.computeHmacSignature()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computeHmacSignature%28MacAlgorithm,String,String%29) to sign the request, although figuring that out will likely be tricky.

As for a nonce, it's probably enough to use the current timestamp, available from `new Date().getTime()`.